# Angular CLI (ng --version) command Error TS and WebPack

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, command-line-interface

After firing a command in VSCode Terminal $ ng --version the following came out.

Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 9.4.0
OS: darwin x64

> Angular: error ... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler,
>   compiler-cli, core ... forms, http, language-service, material,
>   platform-browser ... platform-browser-dynamic, router

typescript: error
webpack: error

Question: Is this the reason I cannot have error in ng serve --open command. How can I resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you run npm install yet?

Comment: can you add what error you are getting and update the post with the configuration

Comment: After running npm install. ng serve --open runs properly and ng --version provides the following:

Comment: Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 9.4.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.3
@angular/cli: 1.6.3
@angular/material: 5.0.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.3
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0

Comment: Thanks, @prasanthv.

Comment: Great, I’ll add it as an answer if you don’t mind.

Answer (score 1):

You may be picking up the global `ng`, which in this case is reporting the versions of project level packages — try `npm install`.